# How did Saint Dnyaneshwar made the ox to recite veda mantras?

Tags: vedas, saint

I heard somewhere (someone posted this on quora and some people said this on twitter as well) that Sant Dnyaneshwar made an ox recite vedas.

Can someone give some reference of this story and also explain the context?

Comment: He was a yogi. He used his yogic Powers (Siddhi) in that miracle.There is no need for any logical explanation as use of such yogic powers are amply mentioned in scriptures. Instead ask about how he did that to happen.

Comment: it's better to ask  only about the story  , asking about logical explanation of yogic phenomenons  is off topic on the forum. Will retract the close vote then.

Comment: removed the logical "reasoning part" just looking for the story and context.

Comment: OK , retracted close vote. BTW  the q. is not easy to answer. There are no authentic biographies of Sant Shree Dnyaneshwar Maharaj available  Also the main problem is although he was a yogi but it's difficult to know that by using which siddhi he did this miracle. Will try to do my best in finding.

Comment: Thank you bro, I guess its widely available as folk story but need some reference